# Updating Multiple Rows in Single Query

Tags: rows

I am having an issue with updating multiple rows. What the intent of what i am trying to do is update all rows that share a common variable increasing a counter by one.

table looks something like this:

```
table name: Inventory

id   item   rep  onhand
1    Screw  Bob  1
2    Bolt   Paul 3
3    Nail   Bob  4
4    Brace  Jen  2
5    Glue   Bob  12
```

What I am trying to do is get all of the onhand for Bob to increase by 1.

The select query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Inventory` WHERE (rep='Bob')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die;
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $onhand=$data[onhand];
```

The update query:

```
$query = "UPDATE `Inventory` SET onhand=($onhand+1) WHERE (rep='Bob')";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die;
```

What happens is Screw will indeed update to 2 but everythng else attached to Bob also updates to the value of 2 not to their value +1. What appears to be happening is it's taking the first value found in the frist record (id #1) and updating all the other records where Bob is rep with that value.

How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET onhand=onhand+1 WHERE rep='Bob'
```

What you really want is to increment onhand by 1.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that and it stil changes all to the new value for the first row.

Comment: okay, let's get to the bottom of this and get it fixed. 1) The select is not needed at all. Please remove that. 2) Please update your question with the latest code that has the correct SQL update statement, and I will take a look.

Comment: Ok when you said to remove the select I changed this line: $query = "UPDATE `Inventory` SET onhand=($onhand+1) WHERE (rep='Bob')";  to  $query = "UPDATE `Inventory` SET onhand=(onhand+1) WHERE (rep='Bob')";<br/>and everything worked, thank you for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested removing the select resolved the problem.  I changed this line: $query = "UPDATE Inventory SET onhand=($onhand+1) WHERE (rep='Bob')"; to $query = "UPDATE Inventory SET onhand=(onhand+1) WHERE (rep='Bob')";
Peter Pei Guo was right on the money.